# Split views in different tabs

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a page where I want the data to be showed in multiple tabs (and the data may only be loaded when clicked on the tab):

**View**

```
@model project.Models.AdminModels.Module

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Module";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title: @Model.Name</h2>
<div class="ui secondary pointing menu">
  <a class="item" asp-controller="Module" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">
    Details
  </a>
  <a class="item" asp-controller="Module" asp-action="Menus" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">
    Menus
  </a>
  </a>
  <a class="item" asp-controller="Module" asp-action="Menus" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">
    Other tabs
  </a>
</div>
<div class="ui segment" id="content">

</div>
```

[image]

Is their a way that I can load the data in the content div, without reloading and redefining the whole page?

Comment: Sure - you can do that. Instead of tag helpers simply attach click event to the tab headers and use ajax calls in Java Script to get the data from the server when clicked (if it's have not already been loaded)

Comment: Oke, thought it would be possible with tag helpers aswell